# Android views of the right side of the screen

Tags: android, xml, layout, hebrew

I want my android app to support more languages (Hebrew), but I can't make the views appear on the right side of the scree (In Hebrew we write/read from right to left unlike English).

I tried `android:layout_gravity="right"` but it didn't work.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`android:layout_gravity` defines position of the view with respect to it's parent.
`android:gravity` defines position of the child views of the current view.

So setting android:gravity will work for you

Also refer to following post to handle screens for multiple languages

[How to get text direction in Android and change layout dynamically according to the direction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18008189/how-to-get-text-direction-in-android-and-change-layout-dynamically-according-to)

Also try setting `android:textDirection` for RTL.

For more info you can go through following link:

http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2013/03/native-rtl-support-in-android-42.html

Answer (score 0):

You can align your text from right to left, for this add this attribute

```
android:gravity="right"
```

to your text view, it works only if your textview width is set to "fill_parent" or to a fixed dip.
*I cant point out a correct solution without seeing your layout, excuse if this solution dont work for you.*

Comment: I have name layouts, mostly Table Layouts with some Table Rows with more than one element in each row.. and the views are not always TextView some are Button etc.