# how to get language of text in a textview?

Tags: android, sms, detection, persian

I have a textview in my android messaging app I get messages of my android phone and I show them in textviews I want to set layout_gravity to right if the text is persian so how can I detect language of text that I get from below uri?

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://sms/");
```

Comment: not understand your question

Comment: @BhavdipPathar what is the problem with it? My app is a sms app, and I am getting messages from database and showing them some of them are wriiten in english and some persian, how can I detect that the sms is in persian or not?

Comment: there are third party options available for language detection. [check this out](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=language+detection+online+apis&oq=language+detection+online+apis&aqs=chrome..69i57.7601j0j1&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8#q=language+detection+google+apis+android).

Comment: I am not sure but you can do using the third pary library or online api making the call request help for language detection. but  I would not suggest to check using API. You can use the third party ib locally check the language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is [Bidi](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/Bidi.html) class. This class has [getBaseLevel()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/Bidi.html#getBaseLevel%28%29) method which returns `0` if your text is `left-to-right` otherwise `1` (if `right-to-left`).

example:

```
@Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;

        Bidi bidi = new Bidi(userList.get(position).getName(), Bidi.DIRECTION_DEFAULT_LEFT_TO_RIGHT);
        if(bidi.getBaseLevel() == 0)
            convertView = myInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_add_friends_row, null);
        else
            convertView = myInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_add_friends_row_mirror, null);
```

---

There is another method, `baseIsLeftToRight()` that might be better to be used in if statement. Result was same as above.

```
Bidi bidi = new Bidi(userList.get(position).getName(), Bidi.DIRECTION_DEFAULT_LEFT_TO_RIGHT);
if(bidi.baseIsLeftToRight())
                convertView = myInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_add_friends_row, null);
            else
                convertView = myInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_add_friends_row_mirror, null);
```

SRC: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18008575/797495

---

```
public final class Bidi
extends Object
```

> This class implements the Unicode Bidirectional Algorithm.
>
> A Bidi object provides information on the bidirectional reordering of
>   the text used to create it. This is required, for example, to properly
>   display Arabic or Hebrew text. These languages are inherently mixed
>   directional, as they order numbers from left-to-right while ordering
>   most other text from right-to-left.
>
> Once created, a Bidi object can be queried to see if the text it
>   represents is all left-to-right or all right-to-left. Such objects are
>   very lightweight and this text is relatively easy to process.
>
> If there are multiple runs of text, information about the runs can be
>   accessed by indexing to get the start, limit, and level of a run. The
>   level represents both the direction and the 'nesting level' of a
>   directional run. Odd levels are right-to-left, while even levels are
>   left-to-right. So for example level 0 represents left-to-right text,
>   while level 1 represents right-to-left text, and level 2 represents
>   left-to-right text embedded in a right-to-left run.

Comment: this will provide locale of phone which may or may not be the language of sms text.

Comment: again this will provide locale of keyboard. Question is about displaying an sms already present in sms inbox of user.

Comment: @RahulTiwari The question doesn't reflect what OP wanted.