# how to get user input method language

Tags: android

I am writing an application which is using a edit text .i want to know whats users input language in oncreate method or when keyboard input type changes. Is there any way to set a listener to get that change? All the answer i found were about locale and not about input language. I don't want to handle locale, locale has no effect in application, the input language does. i used this codes.
    private void printInputLanguages() {

```
List<InputMethodInfo> ims = imm.getEnabledInputMethodList();
for (InputMethodInfo method : ims) {
    List<InputMethodSubtype> submethods = imm
            .getEnabledInputMethodSubtypeList(method, true);
    for (InputMethodSubtype submethod : submethods) {
        if (submethod.getMode().equals("keyboard")) {
            String currentLocale =

            submethod.getLocale();
            tv.setText(currentLocale);
            Log.i("sara", "Available input method locale: "
                    + currentLocale);
        }
    }
}
```

and this codes but none of them wasnt help full.

```
  InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
InputMethodSubtype ims = imm.getCurrentInputMethodSubtype();
String localeString = ims.getLocale();
Locale locale = new Locale(localeString);
String currentLanguage = locale.getDisplayLanguage();
```

and i used this link but again i couldn't solve my problem

[Get keyboard language or detect user input language in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17670922/get-keyboard-language-or-detect-user-input-language-in-android)

pls someone help me to know  to get user input method when activity create.
thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check this: I think all you need is inside, note it's fully working code.

[Android: Detect softkeyboard RTL Vs LTR (language direction)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32949611/android-detect-softkeyboard-rtl-vs-ltr-language-direction)

Here a short code to detect current language of the softkeyboard (on screen keyboard - Input method language): `localeDisplayName` is the language of the keyboard...

```
InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
InputMethodSubtype inputMethodSubtype = inputMethodManager.getCurrentInputMethodSubtype();
Locale mLocale = new Locale(inputMethodSubtype.getLocale());
String localeDisplayName = mLocale.getDisplayName();  //e.g. "English"
```

Comment: can u show me in a example like  the first one in the link?

Comment: @saeed Please check my answer I edited it and if it's work you can notify me via accepting it as an answer.

Comment: I not getting a language code or name .. please help me out !!