# Strange bug in EditText.setText() method for RTL languages in Lenovo devices

Tags: android, android-edittext, right-to-left

I received a **bug report** from my customers about my android application in Lenovo devices.

I noticed when I set the locale of app to a `RTL` language like **Persian** or change the language of Android OS to **Persian**, the `setTex()` method of `EditText`s or `Textview`s inserts two extra characters at the beginning and the end of the original string.

For example:

```
String myString1 = "original string";
int length1 = myString1.length(); // length1 is 15

myEditText.setText(myString1);
String myString2 = myEditText.getText().toString();
int length2 = myString2.length(); // length2 is 17
```

This problem occurs only on Lenovo devices. The `setText()` method adds `LEFT-TO-RIGHT OVERRIDE (U+202D)` at the beginning and `POP DIRECTIONAL FORMATTING (U+202C)`at the end of my string in RTL mode. 
This causes big problems in my application. I have lots of `setText()` methods.
Is there any short solution for solving this this problem?

**Device info:** `Lenovo Tablet TB-8504X, Android 7.1.1`

**Update:**
Is the problem with `Android OS`? Can I find any fix for the device?

Comment: have you tried `trim()` ?

Comment: @JohnJoe I need shorter solution. I have to add lots of trim() method or something like that.

Comment: Not an android dev, so not sure if this may help or not. Please see if https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18008189/how-to-get-text-direction-in-android-and-change-layout-dynamically-according-to is of any help?

Comment: Is your problem with setText() (i.e. layout on the screen), or with getText(), i.e. read what the user changed in the text box?

Comment: @AlexCohn The problem is with `setText()`. Because after calling `setText()` you can erase extra characters by back space.

Comment: It could be pretty tricky to intercept and fix all calls to `setText()`, including the implicit ones. But if your problem can be resolved on the side of `getText()`, there may be a reasonable hack to trim its output. You can get an idea from [this blog](http://shadowwhowalks.blogspot.co.il/2013/02/android-replacing-system-classes.html).

Comment: @AlexCohn I want to know the source of this bug. Why this problem occurs only on this device? Can I find any fix for the OS?

Comment: Unfortunately I could not find a similar device around me to play with. The OS modification are probably not public: the Android license does not require this. You can try to file a complaint on Lenovo's [Android Tablets](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Lenovo-Android-based-Tablets-and/bd-p/lt02_en) board.

Comment: create your custom editText and use trim there.

Answer (score 3):

`.length()` and .`getText().length()` they are identical

**However** `.getText().toString().length()` is different in some cases.

First, it is, not `String`, nothing but `CharSequence`. So, it is based on **formatting**, that may cause to affect on size of calculation.

Comment: This. I am pretty sure, that if you'd used ``CharSequence`` instead of ``String``, the length in both cases would be identical.

Answer (score 2):

The best solution for this is stated in the comments which is to use `.trim()`. But according to what you said,

> I need shorter solution. I have to add lots of trim() method or something like that

it seems like your problem the time consumption of locating each uses and adding `.trim()` to it. If that is the case, just use the replace function of your IDE. You can avoid unnecessary changes by specifying the whole line.

Press **CTRL + SHIFT + R**

`myEditText.getText().toString()`

*with space in the end to avoid something like myEditText.getText().toString().lenght()*

replace by

`myEditText.getText().toString().trim()`

and the other is the line with `;`

`myEditText.getText().toString();`

replace to

`myEditText.getText().toString().trim();`

So this covers all the uses of this editText's value usage. Hope this helps